# Convert string vector to char array in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a string vector to a char array in c++.

More specifically what I'm trying to do is to split a shell command like "ls –latr" by using this:

```
istringstream f(x);
while (getline(f, x, ' '))
{
    strings.push_back(x);
}
```

I believe that will give me `strings[0] == "ls"` and `strings[1]==" -latr"`.

I'm trying then to do the following:

```
execvp(strings[0], strings);
```

however, I get this error:

> error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string, std::allocator >’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int execvp(const char*, char* const*)’

Therefore, I'm trying to figure out how I can convert the strings to a char array.

Comment: add `.c_str()` to the end of `strings[0]`; you'll still have to build another vector of pointers for the second parameter though.

Comment: Assuming strings is a `std::vector<std::string>`, use `strings[0].c_str()`. the second paramater needs an array of pointers, so that's more complex.

Comment: Instead of the getline, you can simply say `while (f >> x) { strings.push_back(x); }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) reveals that "`execvp` provides an array of pointers to null-terminated strings". So you need to create such an array. Here's one way:

```
std::vector<char *> argv(strings.size() + 1);    // one extra for the null

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != strings.size(); ++i)
{
    argv[i] = &strings[i][0];
}

execvp(argv[0], argv.data());
```

Comment: Not enough transform :) I've just added a C++03 proof transform answer. Painful stuff

Comment: @sehe: I can never quite be bothered with `transform`. I always feel it's a lot of work with no gain.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, Boost Range has `transformed`, which is a lot more useful indeed.  However, before C++11 I think it was frequently a "better for_each"

Comment: I've changed it from `strings[i].front()` to `strings[i][0]` so it is always correct, independent of whether the string is empty.

Comment: @KerrekSB : I'm fine with std::vector, but I still have problems remembering how char *s get initialized!

Comment: @Roddy: That's what manuals are for! Vector value-initializes its elements when you create it with a size or when you `resize` and don't provide an initial value.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's wrong with `strings[i].c_str()` here?  You need a C style string.  `std::string` has a function explicitly designed to give you one.

Comment: @KerrekSB And `transform` is a natural here, especially with lambdas.  Why write three or four lines, when one suffices, _and_ says more clearly what you are doing?

Comment: @JamesKanze: You'd have to do all the casting yourself, which just looks bad.

Comment: @KerrekSB True, but again, it is more explicit.  The function _doesn't_ modify the strings, and the `const_cast` says precisely that you are adapting to a legacy interface.  (FWIW, I'd do the cast at the site of the call to `execv`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I tried a couple of alternatives but hated all of them: range loops, transforms, back inserters... nothing looks quite as tolerable to me as the present code. But please go and post your own method!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Do we actually *know* that the strings aren't going to be mutated? I almost asked a question about this at one point.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's one cast (or maybe two) in the call to `execv`.  And it's more or less an expected cast---such casts are frequent when calling into a legacy interface.  To me, `c_str()` and `const_cast` just cry out legacy interface, which is precisely what we have to deal with.

Comment: @KerrekSB Good question.  The example in the Posix standard uses string literals, so it seems safe to suppose that the strings themselves will not be modified.  As for the rest... after `execv`, the `std::vector` et al is gone, so Posix probably feels no need to say anything about it.  (Note that the destructor of the vector will _not_ be called.)  Logically, there's no reason that anything should be modified, and I suspect that there exists code somewhere which counts on this, but Posix is singularly quiet about it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I find `std::transform` very natural when usable.  In C++03, it would require defining a functional object outside of the function to be used.  If the application does a lot of interfacing to C functions which take a `char**`, it might be worth defining such an object for general use; otherwise, it seems like extra work for very little if any gain, and I'd use the loop.  In C++11, however, there's lambda, which makes `std::transform` a clear winner.

Comment: @KerrekSB Re the possibility of any of the arguments actually being modified: I just rechecked the Posix standard: the _pointers_ are declared `const` (the argument type is `char *const []`), and the example uses string literals for the strings themselves, so I think we can be sure that `execv` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with `c_str()` method of `std::string`. It returns C-like string from the `std::string` class, i.e. char * which you need for `execvpe`. Check [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the char array will not be changed you can use

```
strings[0].c_str()
```