# I want to read chunks of data from a file and store it in vector<string> buf. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, file-io, stdvector

The line `file.read((char*)&buf, BUFFER_SIZE);` is not storing any data in buf variable :(

LOOP

```
vector <string> buf;
file.read((char*)&buf,BUFFER_SIZE);
vector<string>::iterator iter = buf.begin();
for ( ;iter < buf.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << "\n  "<< *iter;
}
```

LOOP

Comment: You are looking for this [then][1]. Hope it may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482496/convert-string-vector-to-char-array-in-c

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It is a text file.

Comment: I am not sure :( . I am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: @David Schwartz: My problem is solved overall but I could not answer your question hence, adding this comment.Sorry I don't know how to check the version. But I see that C++11 commands are not available/compiling so I should be C++98.

Comment: @mp123 It seems like you don't understand what the word "type" means in the context of C++. That's kind of scary.

Comment: My bad... I clearly misunderstood ur question ... TWICE... My file was basic_ifstream<char>.

Comment: ifstream file(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.read((char*)&buf, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Doesn't make sense. Did you try to access a buffer inside the vector object? Beside, no buffer has been allocated yet in your code.

```
vector <string> buf;
```

When allocated it will create an internal array of std::string objects. I guess you wanted a buffer of chars rather than string objects?

Write:

```
vector<char> buf;
buf.resize(BUFFER_SIZE);   <<< You need to allocate memory if you want to fill it in yourself
```

Now you can access the allocated buffer:

```
&buf[0];  <<< This is a pointer to internal buffer which is an array of chars.
file.read(&buf[0], BUFFER_SIZE) <<< Reads data into the buffer
```

[vector::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) Returns a reference to the element at position n in the vector container. C++ guarantees that underlying container occupies contiguous memory, that allows to take a pointer of returned value and treat it as a C array.

Comment: file.read() expects a char* , how do I read BUFFER_SIZE from file and store in my vector?. my vector can be char not necessarily string. I just need a buffer full of data equal to the buffer size.

Comment: Thanks, This fixes my read issue :). How do I print the contents of buf to verify it has read correctly? –

Comment: I tried   for( std::vector<char>::iterator iter = buf.begin(); iter != buf.end(); ++iter)
   std::cout << *iter << ' ';    But it is printing only spaces no content.

Comment: What does your file contain? Is it possible that a newline character terminates reading? Does `file.read()` return any result code you may check? Try a C array: `char buf[256]; file.read(buf, 256); printf("%s\n", buf);` Does that read the file correctly?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was able to print the content using above code.  Initially there was no data displayed because I had opened my file with ios::ate. Once I removed that the program is working as expected. Thank you all for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482496/convert-string-vector-to-char-array-in-c).

Hope it may help you to solve your problem.